# Transpose columns and rank values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rank

I have a question about transposing or stacking values in pandas.

I have 1 dataframe

```
| product | s1_value | s2_value | s3_value |
| --------| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| First   | 105      | 103      | 108      |
| Second  | 205      | 186      | 204      |
```

and I want to transform and join them to make the next outcome ( ¿can be in list for then iterate over it and rank? )

```
| stacked_values_p1 |
| ----------------- |
| 105               |
| 103               |
| 108               |
```

Rank the above column with rank function in Pandas, and then have a dataFrame with the inicial data + rank columns, like next based on which value is higher

```
| initial data | ... | s1_rank | s2_rank | s3_rank |
| ------------ | --- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
|     ...      | ... |    2    |    3    |    1    |
|     ...      | ... |    1    |    3    |    2    |
```

I've been reading about stack, transpose, and merge and I'm a bit confused.

Thanks!

Comment: In your first df the column  `s1_value` appears twice. I am assuming the last one is `s3_value`. Is that correct?

Comment: @GonçaloPeres yes, the last one is  `s3_value`, sorry

Comment: Have a go first then we can help if you get stuck.  Try with the [DataFrame.rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) function.

Comment: @Bill `DataFrame.rank` , rank over the entire column and i don't want rank by products, want rank by its values on different stores

Comment: If you look at the docs, you'll see there is an axis argument which allows you to choose rows or columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first use transpose after create index by column `product`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('product').T
print (df1)
product   First  Second
s1_value    105     205
s2_value    103     186
s3_value    108     204
```

For second use [`DataFrame.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) for all columns without first and add to original `DataFrame`:

```
f = lambda x: x.replace('value','rank')
df = df.join(df.iloc[:, 1:].rank(axis=1, ascending=False).astype(int).rename(columns=f))
print (df)
  product  s1_value  s2_value  s3_value  s1_rank  s2_rank  s3_rank
0   First       105       103       108        2        3        1
1  Second       205       186       204        1        3        2
```

Comment: After testing the snippet and adjusting it to my code, it works perfectly. I am still wondering why it is set to `df1`, but then the variable `df1` is not used.

Comment: @VictorCaicedo - because not necessary for second `df` use `df1` ;)

Comment: I was wrong all this time, thinking that I had to create a separate element to be able to use the function.

Sorry Bill.

Comment: @VictorCaicedo - No problem, the best is ask ;)